# Do something after hook

Tags: members, zoo-visitor, login, extension, hook

I'm making an ExpressionEngine extension that is supposed to return to a certain URL **after** the user logged in. I'm using this hook: member_member_login_single. This returns me to the right url, but it doesn't finish the whole login process. In other words: it's not logging my user in! How am I supposed to do this? There doesn't seem to be a hook like member_login_end.

```
 function activate_extension()
{
    $this->settings = array(
        'prijs_per_kind'    => 5,
        'sluitingsdatum'    => '05-11-2016',
    );

    $hooks = array(
            "zoo_visitor_register_end" => "redirectToPayment",
            "member_member_login_single" => "checkClosingDate"
    );

    foreach ($hooks as $hook => $method) {
        $data = array(
                'class' => __CLASS__,
                'method' => $method,
                'hook' => $hook,
                'settings' => serialize($this->settings),
                'priority' => 10,
                'version' => $this->version,
                'enabled' => 'y'
        );
    }
    ee()->db->insert('extensions', $data);
}

function checkClosingDate()
{

        ee()->functions->redirect('http://sportvandemaand.local/account/profiel/verlopen');

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you are killing the process when you throw a redirect. The `redirect()` function basically causes a `die()` affect, ending code termination.

You know you can declare a redirect in the template with the log-in form?

http://ee2docs.com/add-ons/member/index.html#login-form-tag

You just add a `return="your_url"` parameter to the tag.

```
{exp:member:login_form return="your_url"}

    Form stuff here, see reference

{/exp:member:login_form}
```

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason you really *do* need to set the redirect inside of your hook (perhaps, for example, you're performing some additional logic inside your method which you've excised for simplicity), try manually setting the value of `$_POST['RET']` inside your method.

```
$_POST['RET'] = 'account/profiel/verlopen';
```

This value will get processed inside of `Functions::form_backtrack()`, which is called by `Member_auth::_build_success_message()`, which is the last step of `Member_auth:member_login()`.